# Is there a way to sound an audio alert when a breakpoint is hit in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I like to have Eclipse debugging in the background while I do other things, but I can't find a way to sound an audio alert or focus to Eclipse when a breakpoint is hit (I'm using OSX if that matters).

Has anyone found a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the feature is actually not supported by Eclipse, but maybe you can achieve your goal with a workaround on a [conditional breakpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-manage_conditional_breakpoint.htm).

You can try setting the breakpoint as conditional and putting your code to play the audio clip inside it, something like this :

```
....
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(Filename);
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);         
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);

return true;
```

Should work...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Eclipse for C/C++ Developer [has this feature implemented](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_addrmv_brk_action.htm).

It is strange for me that this is available in C/C++ Eclipse version, but not available in Eclipse for Java :(